# mysql query to filter results based on count criteria

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter down the results to show me based upon the following condition: I will write down what I am trying:

I have 4 tables: users, rp,rpa,rpud - all tables have rfID as the Key which is the PK in the users table

Now what I am trying is: Membership = 1 is basic membership

1. Query the users table and rp,rpa,rpud table on the basis that if the user is of basic membership and never signed up for membership [whose record can exist in the rp, rpa if he was member before and then again became a basic member.] and has reached his/her maximun downloads of 3, i should be able to able to show only those people

Here is what i am trying and that seems wrong:

```
SELECT
id,firstname,lastname, membership
FROM
users 
where membership = 1 
and users.rfID not in (select rfID from rp) or users.rfID not in (select rfID from rpa) 
and count(rpud.rfID) <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change your logic from `or` to `and`.  You want all these conditions to be true.

Second, you cannot mention a table name unless you first declare it in the `from` clause.  The following should do what you want:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, membership
FROM users u
where u.membership = 1 and
      u.rfID not in (select rfID from rp) and
      u.rfID not in (select rfID from rpa) and
      u.rfId not in (select rfID from rpud group by rfid having count(*) > 3);
```

EDIT:

For performance, try changing these to `join`s:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, membership
FROM users u left join
     rp
     on rp.rfID = u.rfID left join
     rpa
     on rpa.rfID = u.rfID left join
     (select rfID
      from rpud
      group by rfid
      having count(*) > 3
     ) rpud
     on rpud.rfID = u.rfId
where u.membership = 1 and rp.rfID is null and rpa.rfID is null and rpud.rfID is null;
```

Comment: this is taking a hell lot of time, as each table is beyond 60000+ records